# When loading same component with different data, old data still showing - Angular 5

Tags: angular5, angular-changedetection, angular-renderer2

In an Angular 5 app I am building, I have a side menu and main content menu.

Two of the menu items on the left load the same component with different route data.

By default, Angular uses the same component instance to render both. Hence, the **ngOnInit()** will be called only once (one instance).

The component to render contains a child component (with the change-detection set to **OnPush**). The child component receives the data as **@Input()**

When the first menu item is clicked, data is rendered properly.
When the second menu item is clicked, the **old data is still showing** and once the new data arrives from the server it is rendered.

The behavior mentioned is normal. There is no change **yet** in the data in the parent component and hence the child component **@Input()** were not changed, hence the **ngOnChange()** of the child component is not triggered.

When the data arrives from the server, the parent component will update its data and hence the child component **@Input()** will be updated accordingly and hence **ngOnChange()** will be triggered on the child component. As a result, Angular will update go for a UI rendering.

The goal here is when navigating to the same component, to reset the data beforehand, before even waiting for the new data to arrive.

How is that doable?

Thanks